# How to get pull request from Vercel CLI deployed project?

Tags: vercel

How to get pull request from Vercel CLI deployed project? I have tried many thing like "vercel pull ",vercel import , lots of thing it's not working.

how can i get my code what I have deployed by using Vercel CLI, remember my code isn't in GitHub. so how can i download or pull it on my computer???

advance thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend you start using version control as soon as possible. You usually push from version control to web site, you don't pull deployed code back to make changes. This is especially true when code gets compiled and you'd lose the sources by relying what's deployed.